# Trying to Understand how jquery.done() works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of cascading-option dropdown boxes that I'm trying to populate via javascript & jquery.  In the $(document).ready section I'm trying to implement the jquery .done() function to ensure that each prior function is completed before the next run starts running, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when(getSchoolYears()).done(function () {
        $.when(getDistricts()).done(function () {
            $.when(getAreas()).done(function () {
                $.when(getSchoolTypes()).done(function () {
                    $.when(getSchoolLevels()).done(function () {
                        $.when(getGrades()).done(function () {
                            $.when(getEvents()).done(function () {
                                $.when(getResolutions()).done(function () {
                                    $.when(getSchools()).done(function () {
                                        loadCharts();
                                    })
                                })
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Focusing on the first two functions, getSchoolYears() & getDistricts(), I put consle.log statements into these functions, and the message for getDistricts() gets logged before the message for getSchoolYears()

```
function getSchoolYears() {
    var data = [];
    var param = {};

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        url: "../WebServices/myLocations.asmx/get_SchoolYears",
        data: JSON.stringify(param),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = [];

            data.push(msg.d);

            $('#ddSchoolYear li').remove();

            for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                $('#ddSchoolYear').append(data[i]);
            }

            $('#hidSchoolYear').val(ddSubmitted('#ddSchoolYear input', '#lblYear'));
            console.log('finished');
        }
    });
}

function getDistricts() {
    console.log($('#hidSchoolYear').val());
    var param = { "endYear": $('#hidSchoolYear').val() };

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        url: "../WebServices/myLocations.asmx/get_Districts",
        data: JSON.stringify(param),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            var data = [];

            data.push(msg.d);

            $('#ddDistrict li').remove();

            for (var i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
                $('#ddDistrict').append(data[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Am I not understanding how the .done() function works? Is there a way to ensure that one functions completes before the next one begins?

Comment: you need to `return $.ajax(...` in the first function like you do in the second

Comment: The first chunk of code (inside the document ready) should be able to be written `getSchoolYears()
        .then(getDistricts)
        .then(getAreas)
        .then(getSchoolTypes)
        .then(getSchoolLevels)
        .then(getGrades)
        .then(getEvents)
        .then(getResolutions)
        .then(getSchools)
        .then(loadCharts);` - note the lack of `()` in all but the first function